# What is the difference between Taktteile and Taktglieder?

Tags: theory, terminology

I am reading a book about Metric Manipulations by Danuta Mirka and the author refers to some German words. In this book, he writes that *Takt* refers to measure, *Taktteile* to parts of a measure, *Taktglieder* to members of the measure and *Taktnoten* to the notes of the measure. I don't understand the difference between ''parts of the measure'' and ''members of the measure''.

What is the difference between the *Taktteile* and the *Taktglieder*?

Comment: Could you give us a quotation?

Comment: I Just flipped through the subset Amazon offers and I assume, you mean *Taktglieder*.

Comment: oh yeah... I misspelled it... that is Taktglieder... my bad...

Answer (score 3):

I did not find *Taktglieder* in any of my German musical references, so I have resort to native language knowledge and some assumptions:

- Takt (*measure*) is a sort of time unit.
- Taktteile (*parts of measure*) is a fragment of that unit
- Taktglieder (*members of measure*) are the notes, which populate the [partial] time unit. These meaning of members as denoting the active participants is shared in different uses as group members, committee members etc.

Measure is a sort of a blurry term, since musicians tend not to distinguish exactly as in

> The third measure is really awkward to play

which does not refer to the time unit, but obviously to its contents.

So in laudable tradition the author defines exact terms first (the foreign language makes things easier, since collisions with ones own notion are less likely) and hopefully uses them consistently afterwards.

Does that match the use of terms in your book?

Answer (score 2):

The [Taktteil](http://de.academic.ru/dic.nsf/konversations_lexikon/72593/Taktteil) is determined by the time signature, and it is the basic subdivision of the measure. E.g., in 4/4 time there are four *Taktteile* (each of which is a quarter note), and in 6/8 there are six *Taktteile* (each of which is an eighth note).

The term [Taktglied](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=DWB&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GT00661) is archaic. Note that the link is from Grimm's dictionary, which appeared in the 1850s. The term used to denote subdivisions of a *Taktteil*, i.e., in 4/4 time, a quarter note is a *Taktteil*, and an eight note is a *Taktglied*. As far as I know there is no modern equivalent of the term *Taktglied*.

[beat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(music))

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "members of the measure" is a part of a musical phrase (So the parts you get when dividing a phrase) and "parts of the measure" are the notes, bars and rests.